# MaridDB 10.3.29 prevents me from deleting a foreign key

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

This is a minimal example that triggers the error

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (
  id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE B (
  what tinyint NOT NULL,

  a bigint NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT x FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES A(id),
  CONSTRAINT y CHECK (what > 0)
);


SELECT b.a FROM B b;

ALTER TABLE B DROP CONSTRAINT x;
```

When i run this in a fresh MariaDB instance (docker mariadb:10.3.28) everything works fine.

When MariaDB 10.3.29 was released the query suddenly broke. So, when i run this in a fresh MariaDB instance (docker mariadb:10.3.29) i get the following error message for the last statement:

```
[42S22][1054] (conn=8) Unknown column '`db`.`b`.`what`' in 'CHECK'
```

Some weird observations:

- if i delete the `y` check and add it after dropping `x` everything works
- if i remove the `SELECT` everything works
- the `b` from the error message changes with the table alias from the `SELECT` statement
- running the last statement again shows the same error
- the error message makes no sense at all

So my question: what's wrong with my SQL?

Comment: sorry, yes, the error message also contains `what`

Comment: Reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&rdbms2=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=77b171833b4cc6562fa2a3b99aebd56a If uncomment then the error dissapears. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: @Akina but this works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&rdbms2=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=2925c24a7654c81262f235e2ab876dbe  Weird

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ In my fiddle the insertion fixes the issue too. Even errorneous insertion (with incorrect `what`) or insertion into non-existent table fixes (insertion into A - not fixes).

Comment: this shoulb be a bug report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug in MariaDB. See [the bugtracker](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25672).

They recommended to do `FLUSH TABLES;` before the `ALTER` statement.

I can confirm that this "hides the bug".